# Parameter in XMLHTTP AJAX post request is being altered in translation

Tags: php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Just a quick one, I'm looking to send through a string in an XMLHttpRequest method and am having issues with data translating incorrectly in transit. Here's what I'm sending through:

```
        xmlhttp.open("POST","create_table.php?", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("steamID="+steamID);
```

`steamID` at the time of being entered to the `.send()` method looks like this: **76561198000759657**.

When it comes back out in my php page it looks like this: **76561198000759660**.

For varying steamID's regardless it always almost rounds up the end. Any idea how I can prevent this?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to call my php function in quotations...

So:

```
$().ready(function() {
    retrieveInventory(<?php echo $_GET['steamID']; ?>, 1);
});
```

Needed to be:

```
$().ready(function() {
    retrieveInventory('<?php echo $_GET['steamID']; ?>', 1);
});
```